# Cpp code main thread freezing because of deleting object can be resolved using smart pointers or not?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, smart-pointers

I am using Qt and cpp for my code in which i have created a class holding a lot of data(Let's say ~100MB in RAM). In the destructor of this class i am deleting this data using a while loop. The problem is that when i call the delete of this class main thread freezes as it's busy in deleting this data.
Someone told me that smart pointer is the solution as it'll release the memory automatically and i don't have to call delete explicitly but i doubt as smart pointer will also release the memory in main thread only.
I want to know that the deletion done by smart pointers is done in main thread or not?

Code sample is:
**Example.h**

```html
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <qlist.h>
#include <memory>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <QColor>

class Temp
{
private:
 QList<QColor *> *m_colorList;
public:
 Temp();
 void addList();
 ~Temp();
};

#endif
```

**Example.cpp**

```html
Temp::Temp()
{
 std::cout<<"Temp Constructor"<<std::endl;
 m_colorList = new QList<QColor *>;
}

Temp::~Temp()
{
 for(int i=0;i<m_colorList->size();i++)
  delete m_colorList->at(i);
 delete m_colorList;
}

void Temp::addList()
{
 QColor *color;
 for(int i =0; i<=2000000; i++)
 {
  color = new QColor(10,20,50,255);
  m_colorList->append(color);
 }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv)
{
 Temp *tempObj = new Temp();
 qDebug()<<"Adding list";
 tempObj->addList();
 qDebug()<<"List added";
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  qDebug()<<i;
 qDebug()<<"deleting list";
 delete tempObj;
 tempObj=NULL;
 qDebug()<<"Memory deleted";
 getchar();
}
```

Comment: Add your code sample, please

Comment: Somewhat depends on your smart pointer - for a shared_ptr, deletion is done by the thread that removed the last reference to the object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smart pointer will delete the object for you automatically.That's all.  under the covers a smart pointer will be calling delete for you - and that will execute the destructor anyway.

Nothing will run in a different thread unless you've set it up to execute in a different thread. While you can do this deletion in a thread, you will then be responsible for ensuring nothing in the main thread accesses the object while its being deleted - obviously if you try to access part of the object as its being deleted (or afterwards) then you will probably crash your program.

Comment: It means if last object (which was using smart pointer) is being deleted in the main thread then destructor of smart pointer will also run in main thread?

Comment: Thanx for looking into this problem. The description told by @gbjbaanb is correct. destructor is being called in main thread only.